# Executing Stored Procedure in Select Statement Column List

Tags: sql-server

I followed the answer provided.

```
SELECT 'EXEC sp_whatever ' + CAST(field1 AS varchar) + ', ' + CAST(field2 AS varchar)
FROM your_table
```

Below is the one, I am trying to achieve. Can anyone tell me where am I making a mistake. I want to pass 4 parameters of type int, bit, int, datetime.

It is displaying error as "*Conversion failed when converting the varchar value 'EXEC My_SP' to data type int.*"

```
SELECT 'EXEC My_SP ' +cast(90 as int)+','+cast(0 as bit)+','+cast(1 as int)+','+ CAST('2016-04-20 00:00:00.000' as datetime) 

SELECT CONCAT('EXEC USP_GetSchedular ', cast(90 as varchar(max)), ',', cast(0as varchar(max)), ',', cast(1 as varchar(max)), ',', '''2016-04-20''')

  from tbl1l Join 

  tbl2 p 

  On l.PromoCode=p.PromoCode and StatusId in(Select StatusId 
                                             From Status 
                                             Where [Status] NOT IN('Deleted','Closed','Rejected By ISAdmin','RejectedBySales','Expired')) 

 and l.IsDealRegLead=1 and l.IsAntipiracy=0 and l.ISLHLead=0 and convert(date,l.createddatetime)<='2016-04-20'
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `CONCAT` operator:

```
SELECT CONCAT('EXEC My_SP ', 90, ',', 0, ',', 1, ',', '''2016-04-20''')
```

Or `CAST` all concatenated parts to varchar.

You can read about `Data Type Precedence (Transact-SQL)` here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190309(v=sql.120).aspx

P.S. If just want to execute your SP:

```
DECLARE @v1 int;
DECLARE @v2 bit;
DECLARE @v3 int;
DECLARE @v4 datetime;
SELECT @v1 = col1, @v2 = col2, @v3 = col3, @v4 = col4
    FROM YourTable;
EXEC My_SP @v1, @v2, @v3, @v4;
```

Comment: I have Stored Procedure-1 from which i need to call stored procedure-2 via a select statement in stored procedure-1. For Eg: In SP-1 Select exec SP-2(parameters) from mytable

Comment: You should first select params into variables and then execute SP2

Comment: Sorry to both of you. Let me clear the air with my proper requirement.
I have a procedure which archives data from a table and move it to another table meant for archival. The date parameter which i am passing is meant to archive the records till that date. The records can be in thousands. What i need is to execute the SP from a select statement specified in another SP. Please check the code in the edited question.

Comment: In this case better to use `CURSOR`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to join those values together, you're going to need to join them as varchars

```
SELECT 
    'EXEC My_SP ' 
     +cast(90 as VARCHAR(2))
     +','
     +cast(0 as CHAR(1))
     +','
     +cast(1 as CHAR(1))
     +','
     + CAST('2016-04-20 00:00:00.000' as VARCHAR(25));
```

That's not going to execute it though, just select it as 1 string.

---

If you want to execute the Stored Procedure with those parameters the syntax is

EXECUTE procedure_name parameter01, parameter02,...parameterN:

```
EXEC My_Sp 90, 0, 1, '20160420'
```

The parameters should be in the same order as defined in the Stored Procedure.

So if the "90 as INT" is the first parameter then it should be called first and if datetime is really the last parameter, then it should be called last.

The only way around this is if you know the parameters name and reference them that way.

Example:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE test_sproc @x int, @y datetime 
AS
BEGIN
SELECT 
    @x as [x]
    , @y as [y]
END

EXECUTE test_sproc @x = 90, @y = '20160420';
```

Comment: Thanks for your responses. But its not executing, do you have any alternative to do so.

Comment: You need to explain why it isn't executing. Getting an error? post it.

Comment: No i am not getting any error but it is not executing SP from Select Statement as it is treating it as a column value.
 SELECT CONCAT('EXEC USP_GetSchedular ', 90 , ',', 0 , ',', 1 , ',', '''2016-04-20''')from tbl as per Ruslan's comments it is returning it as string 'EXEC USP_GetSchedular 90,0,1,'2016-04-20''

Comment: you seem to be mixing mine and Ruslan K.'s answer. Did you try this?
EXEC My_Sp 90, 0, 1, '20160420'

Comment: I need something like this.
Select exec SP(parameters) from mytable. It will work with Function but since the SP is already available i want to use the SP itself.

Comment: Not a major fan of cursor's but Ruslan K.'s comment is probably the best in this case, seeing as a WHILE loop is basically the same thing.

Comment: Just an observation: you never, ever need VARCHAR(1). That is just silly.

Comment: You're absolutely right @BrianStork, answer updated to reflect. Thanks